# How to choose an electronic connector/cable that works in a vibrating environment?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, power-electronics

We are designing a diagnostic electronic tool for a vibrating table.

In our PCB there are a gyroscope, an accelerometer and a bluetooth module.
Our PCB is attached to a vibrating table that works at 12 Hz with 10 mm peak-to-peak amplitude. It has to work for at least three years "always on".

When we are choosing the power connector, what are the technical elements we have to check before buying one? Are there special connectors for that specific use? "Vibrating-environment connectors"?

We are going to pot the pcb.

Our fear is that with that amplitude and with that frequency a normal soldered connector would fail and break itself.

Comment: Wireless power transfer comes to mind.  [I'm half-serious.]

Comment: @NickAlexeev We half did that but it's not appropriate for our particular application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some type of strain relief on the power cable.

Clamp it down half an inch away from the connection point. That reduces the amount of flex on power connector.

Answer (score 1):

Anderson PowerPole connectors are used in high vibration critical systems to make reliable connections. At the board use a ring terminal and screw with a Nylock locknut.

I always solder the cables (no crimp) and use Silicone high strand count wires, the type used by radio control model battery power systems.

Strain relief may be needed if there is a large differential movement between parts - otherwise leave the cables over-length and allow them to flex naturally.

Arbutus